# How do I edit a Discord bot command's description as shown in the default help command?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I am developing a Discord bot with Python. When a user calls the `help` command on a specific command, the bot sends back the command specified -- but no description on that command (except for the default help command itself).

For example:

```
User: e!help question
Bot: e!question [question...]
```

But the description for the `help` command was already defined:

```
User: e!help help
Bot: e!help [commands...] | Shows this message.
```

How would I edit the description of a command?

Answer (score 9):

You can use `brief` and `description` when creating commands to add details to the help command. See example code below.

```
from discord.ext import commands

bot_prefix = '!'

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=bot_prefix)

@client.command(brief='This is the brief description', description='This is the full description')
async def foo():
    await client.say('bar')

client.run('TOKEN')
```

Using `!help` will display the following

```
​No Category:
  help Shows this message.
  foo  This is the brief description

Type !help command for more info on a command.
You can also type !help category for more info on a category.
```

Using `!help foo` will display the following

```
This is the full description

!foo
```

Comment: How would you do this for methods with arguments (parameters)?

Comment: You can override the default by using [`usage`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Command.usage)